# Trying to grep results to a file using a certain pattern, weird behavior occurring

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I am trying to grep a log file and pass the results into output.txt. This is my current attempt:

`grep -n -i "admin"  mylog.log * > output.txt`

I am trying to take anything from the log with "admin" in it. However I have two issues:

1. I actually want any line that has "admin" UNLESS it's "administer.png"
2. For some reason in my terminal, after a while it starts spitting out strange messages like:

   grep: OneOfMyFolders: Is a directory

   grep: SomeOtherFolder: Is a directory

   ...

Why is it doing this and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The following will remove lines with administer.png

```
 grep -n -i "admin" mylog.log * | grep -v "administer.png" > output.txt
```

2) You are asking for grep to look at all files (yes, directories are treated as files) because of the * wildcard.  Remove the * if the only file you care about is mylog.log.  Or try another wild card expression such as *.log (assuming all the files you care about have a .log extension) or *.* (if the files contain an extension and the directories do not).

Comment: What is -v doing? Excluding?

Comment: -v is the switch to remove lines..   man grep  should show you the information about the command and all of the switches that can be used

Comment: Is there no way to use some kind of regular expression instead? like "include this but not this or this or this"?

Comment: The only way I know to do it is by two searches.  Igor's answer is looking for an exact match of "admin" which is the better answer if that is the only word you are interested in... but I have the sense that you might be looking for other words containing the string "admin"

Answer (score 3):

Delete  the "*" after mylog.log to avoid processing other files in your directory.

Use `grep -r "\bWORD\b"` to math a whole word only.

```
grep -n -i -r "\badmin\b"  mylog.log  > output.txt
```